# Open SwiftUI Sheet to medium, but have option to resize to small/large

Tags: swiftui

So I have the following private function:

```
private var userCreateAccount: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .center) {
        Text("New MapGliders? [Create Account](user-register)")
            .font(Font.custom("Nunito-Regular", size: 16))
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
                switch url.absoluteString {
                case "user-register":
                    showUserRegisterSheet = true
                    return .handled
                default:
                    return .discarded
                }
            })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showUserRegisterSheet) {
                RegisterUserSheetView()
                    .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            }
    }
    .padding(.top, 10)
}
```

I am using `.presentationDetents()` to have two sizes for views such as `.medium` and `.large`.

Is it possible to load the sheet as `.medium` by default, but then have the options of using `.small` and `.large` for the views?

When I pass in `.small` inside the presentationDetents, it opens `.small` by default.

Comment: Do you mean https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart/presentationdetents(_:selection:) ? Lets you set the current detent as you are configuring the available detents.

Comment: This is exactly it, thanks Matt!

Comment: I'll give it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the big brother of your `presentationDetents` method, [`presentationDetents(_:selection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chart/presentationdetents(_:selection:)). The second parameter lets you set the current detente (and lets you respond when the user changes detents).

Comment: Thanks Matt! This was the perfect answer, would you mind upvoting my post if the question made sense, would appreciate it :)